# Is it obligatory to write the word "as" twice in comparison of equality?

Tags: grammar, comparisons, charles-dickens, convention

This really baffles me since I've always regarded the "as...as" form as standard but I've heard a lot of people say phrases like "cool as heck" and even "solitary as an oyster" by the learned Charles Dickens. Shouldn't there have been another "as" in front of it? My sincere thanks in advance.

Comment: There is deletion here. In an introductory phrase, I'd say it's fairly standard, perhaps literary  ('Solitary as an oyster, he lived in a secluded cove miles from the busy port'). But other usages probably verge on slang.

Comment: It's the modifying adverb of degree "as" that is dropped. Common enough I suppose in informal speech.